# Extracting Quarterly data from unordered and unevenly spaced data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, time-series, lubridate

Apologies, I am a complete beginner with R

I have a dataframe which contains reporting periods, these are done in interval of Quarters of differing lengths (3mo, 6mo, 9mo, 12mo) example:

| Start | End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 31/12/2022 | 800 |
| 01/01/2022 | 30/09/2022 | 600 |
| 01/07/2022 | 30/09/2022 | 200 |
| 01/01/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 400 |
| 01/04/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 100 |
| 01/01/2022 | 31/03/2022 | 300 |
| 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 | 500 |
| 01/01/2021 | 30/09/2021 | 300 |
| 01/07/2021 | 30/09/2021 | 100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 30/06/2021 | 200 |
| 01/04/2021 | 30/06/2021 | 150 |
| 01/01/2021 | 31/03/2021 | 50 |
| 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2020 | 300 |
| 01/10/2020 | 31/12/2020 | 75 |
| 01/01/2020 | 30/09/2020 | 225 |
| 01/07/2020 | 30/09/2020 | 100 |
| .......... | .......... | ... |

---

The intervals for the above table are:

| Start | End | Value | Intervals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 31/12/2022 | 800 | 2022 Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 |
| 01/01/2022 | 30/09/2022 | 600 | 2022 Q1,Q2,Q3 |
| 01/07/2022 | 30/09/2022 | 200 | 2022 Q3 |
| 01/01/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 400 | 2022 Q1,Q2 |
| 01/04/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 100 | 2022 Q2 |
| 01/01/2022 | 31/03/2022 | 300 | 2022 Q1 |
| 01/01/2021 | 31/12/2021 | 500 | 2021 Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 |
| 01/01/2021 | 30/09/2021 | 300 | 2021 Q1,Q2,Q3 |
| 01/07/2021 | 30/09/2021 | 100 | 2021 Q3 |
| 01/01/2021 | 30/06/2021 | 200 | 2021 Q1,Q2 |
| 01/04/2021 | 30/06/2021 | 150 | 2021 Q2 |
| 01/01/2021 | 31/03/2021 | 50 | 2021 Q1 |
| 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2020 | 300 | 2020 Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 |
| 01/10/2020 | 31/12/2020 | 75 | 2020 Q4 |
| 01/01/2020 | 30/09/2020 | 225 | 2020 Q1,Q2,Q3 |
| 01/07/2020 | 30/09/2020 | 100 | 2020 Q3 |
| .......... | .......... | ... | ....... |

---

I am trying to extract the Quarterly info such that I am left with a dataframe:

| Quarter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022Q4 | 200 |
| 2022Q3 | 200 |
| 2022Q2 | 100 |
| 2022Q1 | 300 |
| 2021Q4 | 200 |
| 2021Q3 | 100 |
| 2021Q2 | 150 |
| 2021Q1 | 50 |
| 2020Q4 | 75 |
| ...... | .. |

---

I have tried using the lubridate package to extract the interval between the start and end dates

**i.e: sprintf("%02d", abs(round(interval(df$start, df$end) / months(1) / 3) * 3))**

to calculate the interval in multiples of 3 months

However, this produces '**202203**' for each of:

| Start | End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/07/2022 | 30/09/2022 | 200 |
| 01/04/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 100 |
| 01/01/2022 | 31/03/2022 | 300 |

---

In some instances, the underlying dataset will change and reporting periods will have different start dates

i.e Q1 will run from Feb - April rather than Jan - March

Is there any way to create a function to extract this as stated above at just a quarterly level per rolling 3 months?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'm not clear on the logic - if a project spans 4 quarters, should the value go into the sum for the final Q or be averaged across all 4?  What about if it's a 6-month project but the rolling window includes 2 of those months?

Comment: Did you know that same as lubridate can tell you the year of a date, it can tell the quarter ? `lubridate::year(Sys.Date())`   ....  `lubridate::quarter(Sys.Date())`